TeXify with IntelliJ IDEA for Mac M1 (Silicon) remains in an endless background process: "Updating indexes"
I installed MacTeX from Homebrew by running the command:
brew install --cask mactex

Then, in IntelliJ IDEA CE I installed the TeXify and PDFView plugin.
When I try to create my first LaTeX-based project, it creates, but a background process appears that never ends: Updatind indexes

Is there a way to fix this, or do I need to install something else?

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

try https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/issues/3675#issuecomment-2393222666

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I executed tlmgr update --self --all at terminal and it's updating a lot of packages I think alphabetically... Now it's going for the packages that start with the letter "b" and it's been a while, so it seems like this process will take some time. When I'm done I'll tell you what happened.

While you wait, you could disable the indexing... https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/issues/3675#issuecomment-2393222666

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It is not clear to me how I should disable indexing. Sorry. How can I do this?

Probably somewhere in the editor's settings

The problem was caused by outdated software.
I solved it by doing the following:

Update all LaTeX packages by running this command in Terminal:
 sudo tlmgr update --self --all


Update IntelliJ IDEA to its latest version (2024.2.4)

Update TeXify to its latest version (0.9.7)


With these three updates the problem has been solved.
